# How is this high-order function working?

Tags: javascript

So I'm a relatively inexperienced developer. I'm going through *Eloquent Javascript* right now and I came across a function that I can't really see the logic behind. When the function noisy is being called, why are there two sets of parenthesis to pass parameters?

```
function noisy(f) {
  return function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
  };
}
noisy(Boolean)(0);
// → calling with 0
// → called with 0 - got false
```

Comment: Because `noisy` returns a function. So that second set of parens calls the returned function.

Comment: Not sure what the intention of noisy is other than to output what is happening. Noisy takes a function as a parameter then returns a different function. Calling that function (the second set of parentheses, like `var newFunction = noisy(Boolean); newFunction(0)`) then runs the initial function (`Boolean`) in order to create a value out of the whatever value you pass in (`0`) and it logs to the console then returns the new value.